# Problems defining a new medium model (Modelica.Media)

Tags: modelica

I'm trying to set up a new medium model on the basis of Modelica.Media. My model extends from PartialMixtureMedium. When simulating an open vessel (taken from Modelica.Fluid), which has neither feed nor drain but is heated from the outside, the mass balance is not fulfilled. While der(m) remains zero, m increases heavily.

Does anybody have a hint for me?

Thanks in advance

TIMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure that your problem is with the medium model. If partial derivatives with respect to composition or density are wrong (and used in the model), it is possible that the medium model causes the problem, but without more information I cannot determine this. There can be other reasons, the open vessel is only valid for liquids, and if your fluid model would be boiling or in the two phase region, it may be outside the validity region of the vessel model.

Hubertus

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. Your hint made me - once again - look even closer at my definition of the derivative of density. There I found an error that caused the failure of mass balance. Now it works!

Thanks again,
TIMO.